# Spring Oauth2 implicit flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

Working on implementing Oauth2 with Spring. I want to implement the implicit workflow:

My configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class App {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
                throws Exception {
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager auth;

        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        @Bean
        public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(DBConnector.dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(DBConnector.dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
                throws Exception {
            security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                    .authenticationManager(auth).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .approvalStoreDisabled();            
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.jdbc(DBConnector.dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                    .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .secret("test")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                            "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(0);

            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off 
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(DBConnector.dataSource).withUser("dave")
                .password("secret").roles("USER");

        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

This is working so far. A user is also generated in the database.

Problem is following. When i try to do following request:

http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=dave&password=secret

I always get a popup window (authentication) asking me to enter a username and a password. But it doesn't matter what i enter there i never pass through. So what is wrong there?

I would like to have it, that when i call this url, that i get back my access_token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of implicit flow all token will be generated through authorization url instead of token url. so you should hit ../oauth/authorize endpoint with implicit response type. i.e

```
../oauth/authorize?response_type=implicit&client_id=trusted_client&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri-of-client-application>.
```

You are getting the username password popup because token endpoint is already protected through spring's BasicAuthenticationFilter and it is expecting you to pass your client_id as username and client_secret as password. Instead of token endpoint you need to protect authorization endpoint so do your endpoint security configuration as given...

```
 @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you disabling cross site request forgery?

Comment: Implicit Grant flow `response_type` value must be set `token` see [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.1)

Comment: but how to get token without basic authentication ?  (even if i configure .permitAll() ),  Spring always complains: Access is denied (user is anonymous)
and doesn't generate token

Comment: `response_type=implicit` does not exist. It would be `response_type=token` instead.